# GCP dataflow with python. "AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_JsonSink' on module 'dataflow_worker.start'

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am new in GCP dataflow.

I try to read text files(one-line JSON string) into JSON format from GCP cloud storage, then split it based on values of certain field and output to GCP cloud storage (as JSON string text file).

Here is [my code](https://gist.github.com/frankShih/065aaff7a7b0b296a41ee7a4ab4bb706)

However, I encounter some error on GCP dataflow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 169, in <module>
    run()
  File "main.py", line 163, in run
    shard_name_template='')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipeline.py", line 426, in __exit__
    self.run().wait_until_finish()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\dataflow\dataflow_runner.py", line 1346, in wait_until_finish
    (self.state, getattr(self._runner, 'last_error_msg', None)), self)
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 773, in run
    self._load_main_session(self.local_staging_directory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 489, in _load_main_session
    pickler.load_session(session_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 287, in load_session
    return dill.load_session(file_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 410, in load_session
    module = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 474, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_JsonSink' on <module 'dataflow_worker.start' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/start.py'>
```

I am able to run this script locally, but it fails when I try to use `dataflowRunner`

Please give me some suggestions.

PS. apache-beam version: 2.15.0

**[Update1]**

I try @Yueyang Qiu suggestion, add

```
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
```

The provided link says:

> DoFn's in this workflow relies on global context (e.g., a module
>   imported at module level)

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq) supports the suggestion above.

However, the same error occurred.

So, I am thinking whether my implementation of _JsonSink (inherit from filebasedsink.FileBasedSink) is wrong or something else needed to be added.

Any opinion would be appreciated, thank you all!

Answer (score 13):

You have encountered a known issue that currently (as of 2.17.0 release), Beam does not support `super()` calls in main module on Python 3. Please take a look at possible solutions in [BEAM-6158](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6158?focusedCommentId=16919945&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16919945). Udi's answer is a good way to address this until BEAM-6158 is resolved, this way you don't have to run your pipeline on Python 2.

Answer (score 7):

Using the guidelines from [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#multiple-file-dependencies), I managed get your example to run.

Directory structure:

```
./setup.py
./dataflow_json
./dataflow_json/dataflow_json.py  (no change from your example)
./dataflow_json/__init__.py  (empty file)
./main.py
```

setup.py:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
  name='dataflow_json',
  version='1.0',
  install_requires=[],
  packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

main.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from dataflow_json import dataflow_json

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataflow_json.run()
```

and you run the pipeline with `python main.py`.

Basically what's happening is that the `'--setup_file=./setup.py'` flag tells Beam to create a package and install it on the Dataflow remote worker. The `__init__.py` file is required for setuptools to identify the `dataflow_json/` directory as a package.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

I finally find out the problem:

the class '_jsonsink' I implement using some features form Python3

However, I do not aware of what version of Python I am using for 'Dataflowrunner'
(Actually, I have not figured out how to specify the python version for dataflow runner on GCP. Any suggestions?)

Hence, I re-write my code to Python2-compatible version, everything works fine!

Thanks for all of you!

Comment: Hi! The process of migration of Dataflow runner to python 3 is currently taking place. You can see the updates on the supported features here!

https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1251?subTaskView=unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting option `save_main_session = True` as in here: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a2b0ad14f1525d1a645cb26f5b8ec45692d9d54e/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/coders.py#L88.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. 
I try it and the error mentioned above disappeared and another error shows up:
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libs' ", where 'libs' are my local modules. 

Does it mean that I can not use the local module with dataflowRunner? (everything is fine on local)

Comment: Check if there is an indentation problem and follow this doc: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors

Comment: @MonicaPC
I have read that article before, but I do not find any good solution to solve my case. Hence, I try to simplify my problem.
Now, a single file with a self-implemented class for data output. But it can not be recognized by dataflowRunner.