# How do I run Apache Beam Integration tests?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to run the game stats example pipeline and integration tests found here https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/game but I'm not sure what is the correct way to set up my local environment.

My main goal is to learn how to use the TestDataflowRunner so that I can implement integration tests for existing pipelines that I have written.

[UPDATE]
I have written a basic dataflow which reads a message from PubSub and writes it to a different topic. I have an integration test that is passing using the TestDirectRunner but I am getting errors when trying to use the TestDataflowRunner

`pipeline.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
import logging

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions


def run(argv=None):
  """Build and run the pipeline."""
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()  
  parser.add_argument('--output_topic', required=True)
  parser.add_argument('--input_subscription', required=True)

  known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
  pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    # Read from PubSub into a PCollection.
    messages = (
        p |
        beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.input_subscription).
        with_output_types(bytes)
    )

    lines = messages | 'decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))

    def format_pubsub(msg):
        logging.info(f'Format PubSub: {msg}')
        return str(msg)

    output = (
        lines
        | 'format' >> beam.Map(format_pubsub)
        | 'encode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8')).with_output_types(bytes))

    output | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(known_args.output_topic)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
  run()
```

`pubsub_it_test.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import logging
import os
import time
import unittest
import uuid

from hamcrest.core.core.allof import all_of
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

from apache_beam.io.gcp.tests import utils
from apache_beam.io.gcp.tests.pubsub_matcher import PubSubMessageMatcher
from apache_beam.runners.runner import PipelineState
from apache_beam.testing import test_utils
from apache_beam.testing.pipeline_verifiers import PipelineStateMatcher
from apache_beam.testing.test_pipeline import TestPipeline

import pipeline


INPUT_TOPIC = 'wordcount-input'
OUTPUT_TOPIC = 'wordcount-output'
INPUT_SUB = 'wordcount-input-sub'
OUTPUT_SUB = 'wordcount-output-sub'

DEFAULT_INPUT_NUMBERS = 1
WAIT_UNTIL_FINISH_DURATION = 12 * 60 * 1000  # in milliseconds


class TestIT(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.test_pipeline = TestPipeline(is_integration_test=True)
        self.project = self.test_pipeline.get_option('project')
        self.uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())

        # Set up PubSub environment.
        from google.cloud import pubsub
        self.pub_client = pubsub.PublisherClient()
        self.input_topic = self.pub_client.create_topic(
            self.pub_client.topic_path(self.project, INPUT_TOPIC + self.uuid))
        self.output_topic = self.pub_client.create_topic(
            self.pub_client.topic_path(self.project, OUTPUT_TOPIC + self.uuid))

        self.sub_client = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
        self.input_sub = self.sub_client.create_subscription(
            self.sub_client.subscription_path(self.project, INPUT_SUB + self.uuid),
            self.input_topic.name)
        self.output_sub = self.sub_client.create_subscription(
            self.sub_client.subscription_path(self.project, OUTPUT_SUB + self.uuid),
            self.output_topic.name,
            ack_deadline_seconds=60)
    
    def _inject_numbers(self, topic, num_messages):
        """Inject numbers as test data to PubSub."""
        logging.debug('Injecting %d numbers to topic %s', num_messages, topic.name)
        for n in range(num_messages):
            self.pub_client.publish(self.input_topic.name, str(n).encode('utf-8'))

    def tearDown(self):
        test_utils.cleanup_subscriptions(self.sub_client, [self.input_sub, self.output_sub])
        test_utils.cleanup_topics(self.pub_client, [self.input_topic, self.output_topic])
  
    @attr('IT')
    def test_pubsub_pipe_it(self):
        # Build expected dataset.
        expected_msg = [('%d' % num).encode('utf-8') for num in range(DEFAULT_INPUT_NUMBERS)]

        # Set extra options to the pipeline for test purpose
        state_verifier = PipelineStateMatcher(PipelineState.RUNNING)
        pubsub_msg_verifier = PubSubMessageMatcher(self.project, self.output_sub.name, expected_msg, timeout=400)
        extra_opts = {
            'input_subscription': self.input_sub.name,
            'output_topic': self.output_topic.name,
            'wait_until_finish_duration': WAIT_UNTIL_FINISH_DURATION,
            'on_success_matcher': all_of(state_verifier, pubsub_msg_verifier)
        }

        # Generate input data and inject to PubSub.
        self._inject_numbers(self.input_topic, DEFAULT_INPUT_NUMBERS)

        # Get pipeline options from command argument: --test-pipeline-options,
        # and start pipeline job by calling pipeline main function.
        pipeline.run(self.test_pipeline.get_full_options_as_args(**extra_opts))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    unittest.main()
```

I am getting this error in the dataflow logs

```
Error message from worker: generic::unknown: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 290, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
    return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 826, in _import_module
    return __import__(import_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pipeline'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 289, in _execute
    response = task()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 362, in <lambda>
    lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 607, in do_instruction
    getattr(request, request_type), request.instruction_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 638, in process_bundle
    instruction_id, request.process_bundle_descriptor_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 467, in get
    self.data_channel_factory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 868, in __init__
    self.ops = self.create_execution_tree(self.process_bundle_descriptor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 925, in create_execution_tree
    descriptor.transforms, key=topological_height, reverse=True)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 924, in <listcomp>
    get_operation(transform_id))) for transform_id in sorted(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 812, in wrapper
    result = cache[args] = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 906, in get_operation
    pcoll_id in descriptor.transforms[transform_id].outputs.items()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 906, in <dictcomp>
    pcoll_id in descriptor.transforms[transform_id].outputs.items()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 904, in <listcomp>
    tag: [get_operation(op) for op in pcoll_consumers[pcoll_id]]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 812, in wrapper
    result = cache[args] = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 906, in get_operation
    pcoll_id in descriptor.transforms[transform_id].outputs.items()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 906, in <dictcomp>
    pcoll_id in descriptor.transforms[transform_id].outputs.items()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 904, in <listcomp>
    tag: [get_operation(op) for op in pcoll_consumers[pcoll_id]]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 812, in wrapper
    result = cache[args] = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 906, in get_operation
    pcoll_id in descriptor.transforms[transform_id].outputs.items()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 906, in <dictcomp>
    pcoll_id in descriptor.transforms[transform_id].outputs.items()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 904, in <listcomp>
    tag: [get_operation(op) for op in pcoll_consumers[pcoll_id]]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 812, in wrapper
    result = cache[args] = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 909, in get_operation
    transform_id, transform_consumers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1198, in create_operation
    return creator(self, transform_id, transform_proto, payload, consumers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1546, in create_par_do
    parameter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1582, in _create_pardo_operation
    dofn_data = pickler.loads(serialized_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 294, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
    return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 826, in _import_module
    return __import__(import_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pipeline'

passed through:
==>
    dist_proc/dax/workflow/worker/fnapi_service.cc:631
```

The command I'm running is

```
pytest --log-cli-level=INFO pubsub_it_test.py --test-pipeline-options="--runner=TestDataflowRunner \
    --project=$PROJECT --region=europe-west1 \
    --staging_location=gs://$BUCKET/staging \
    --temp_location=gs://$BUCKET/temp \
    --job_name=it-test-pipeline \
    --setup_file ./setup.py"
```

My repo for this pipeline can be found here https://github.com/tunnelWithAC/apache-beam-integration-test

Thanks

Comment: You can try starting with this [dataflow quick start](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python), this shows how to run dataflow locally and via dataflow service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integration tests are designed to be run by Beam's CI/CD infrastructure. They are `nose` based and require a custom plugin to understand the `--test-pipeline-options` flag. I wouldn't recommend going this route.

I would follow the [quick start](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python) guide that Ricco D suggested for the environment. You could use pytest to run the integration test. To use the same `--test-pipeline-options` flag, you'll need [this definition](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d6b020ac8f3915b531a85ebaaf98a96319d5b0cc/sdks/python/conftest.py#L28). Otherwise the wordcount example shows how to set up your own command line flags.

---

Update:

I used this to set up the virtualenv:

```
pip install apache-beam[gcp,test]
```

The `test` tag pulls in pytest, but should not be required if you already have pytest installed.

I then created this `conftest.py` file to configure pytest (based on Beam's own conftest.py):

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
  parser.addoption('--test-pipeline-options',
                   help='Options to use in test pipelines. NOTE: Tests may '
                        'ignore some or all of these options.')
```

To run the test:

```
pytest --log-cli-level=INFO pipeline_it_test.py --test-pipeline-options="--runner=TestDataflowRunner --project=PROJECT --region=us-west1 --staging_location=gs://BUCKET/staging --temp_location=gs://BUCKET/temp --output=gs://BUCKET/output "
```

Not all options in --test-pipeline-options may be required for your test.

Comment: Can you share an example of how you run integration tests using PyTest?

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your example code

Comment: Thanks for all of your help so far. I am able run tests successfully using the TestDirectRunner but I am getting errors with the TestDataflowError. I have added my latest code and the errors above, can you let me know if you know what is causing this problem?

Comment: Beam is not finding pipeline.py. From the setup.py in your repo, I think that putting pipeline.py under porter/ will help. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58845832/63302

Comment: Thank you, everything is working now. I really appreciate your help